# What type of connector is this Velodyne interface box GPS connector?

Tags: connector, identification, gps

Velodyne VLP-16 lidar's interface box has this connector. What type is it?
Could not find this from the [manual](http://velodynelidar.com/vlp-16.html).

[image: Velodyne interface box GPS connector]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page 35 of [its user manual](http://velodynelidar.com/docs/manuals/VLP-16%20User%20Manual%20and%20Programming%20Guide%2063-9243%20Rev%20A.pdf) "Appendix B : Interface Box" shows the schematic of the interface box, where the connector is labelled "SM-068B-SRSS-TB".

First Google hit on SM-068B-SRSS-TB is its [Digikey entry](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/SM06B-SRSS-TB%28LF%29%28SN%29/455-1806-1-ND/926877).

What you probably wanted to ask is what connector plugs into it ... hopefully you can get that from Digikey or the manufacturer, JST.